# ValueError: Trying to share variable enco/gru_cell/gates/kernel, but specified shape (512, 512) and found shape (356, 512)

Tags: tensorflow

I encounter an error after I updated my tensorflow-GPU to 1.2.1.
I used encode-decode structure, part of encode's code is:

```
output, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=self.cell,
                              inputs=logits,
                              sequence_length=self.en_len,
                              dtype=tf.float32,
                              scope='enco')
```

and the decode is:

```
output, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=self.cell,
                                      inputs=deco_inputs,
                                      sequence_length=self.de_len,
                                      initial_state=init_state,
                                      dtype=tf.float32,
                                      scope='deco')
```

then, I received the error.
Num of hidden units is 256, embeding size is 100, to check the error, I removed multiRNN and used single GRU cell with:

```
RNN = tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(HIDDEN_UNITs)
```

Here is the full error:

```
ValueError: Trying to share variable enco/gru_cell/gates/kernel, but specified shape (512, 512) and found shape (356, 512).
```

ps. This error never happened in version 1.0.1.

Comment: 1) Do you still see the problem when you do not use MultiRNN? 2) Please show the code where you create `self.cell`.

Comment: 1) yes, to check this error, I used single RNNcell, but the error also exist.   2) The code I pasted in above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem usually appears only when you use `MultiRNNCell`, but in your case it happens even with a single cell because you have *two* RNNs. In short, starting from TensorFlow 1.2 RNN cells should not be reused for different layers of an RNN or for different RNNs. If you want to use a single `GRUCell` for each RNN, you need to call the constructor twice to have two different instances to pass. If you are using `MultiRNNCell`s you should have as well two of these, but also one instance of `GRUCell` per layer on each of these. So:

```
# This is doubly wrong!
# self.cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(
#     [tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(HIDDEN_UNITs)] * NUM_LAYERS)

# Also wrong
# self.cell_encoder = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(
#     [tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(HIDDEN_UNITs)] * NUM_LAYERS)
# self.cell_decoder = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(
#     [tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(HIDDEN_UNITs)] * NUM_LAYERS)

# Still wrong
# self.cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(
#     [tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(HIDDEN_UNITs) for _ in range(NUM_LAYERS)])

# This is the way to go!
self.cell_encoder = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(
    [tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(HIDDEN_UNITs) for _ in range(NUM_LAYERS)])
self.cell_decoder = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(
    [tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(HIDDEN_UNITs) for _ in range(NUM_LAYERS)])
```

And then you build your RNNs:

```
output_encoder, state_encoder = \
    tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=self.cell_encoder,
                      inputs=logits,
                      sequence_length=self.en_len,
                      dtype=tf.float32,
                      scope='enco')
output_decoder, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=self.cell_decoder,
                                      inputs=deco_inputs,
                                      sequence_length=self.de_len,
                                      initial_state=init_state,
                                      dtype=tf.float32,
                                      scope='deco')
```

Comment: Thank you for u answer. I found that when I use two cells respectively,  the error goes away, but I'm not sure it is right. This means, the cells parameters no longer share, but in the version 1.0.1, the cell's parameters were shared. I am confused of that.

Comment: @minorfox So you mean you want both RNNs to actually share the weights? I'm not sure I understand how that makes sense... In any case you would have to reverse the layers and transpose the weights to have the right size, and still I don't think there is any reason why the encoding weights should be the same as the decoding ones...

Comment: I have this question just because in my last version there is no problem when I use the same cell in the both RNNs, but in version 1.2.1 that didn't work, so I think if the used share parameters in V1.0.1. Maybe it is a misconception, hahaha...

Comment: @minorfox Ah, I see, but no, it's not a misconception, it's just that the behavior has changed in TensorFlow 1.2. Before, reusing a cell instance did _not_ mean reusing its weights, but in TensorFlow 1.2 it does. So even if you were using the same cell instance with the previous version, each layer would have its own weights. Otherwise, in fact, it wouldn't possibly work, because the size of the first input and last output are different for the encoder and the decoder, so the weights matrices must also have different shapes.

Comment: Yes, ur right, different layers have different weights, even in the previous version, the just reused not shared, I was wrong.